# Как соединить детей и родителей линиями у ListView?

Tags: java, android

Создаю дерево и зашел в тупик при соединении детей и родителей.
Ниже представлен скрин разметки, соединить нужно Захарова с Ивановым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот, собственно, как отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка ничего из себя не представляет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrows"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Собственно вот так отрисовываю линии:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TreeListViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tree_view_cell, parent, false);
        holder = new TreeListViewHolder();
        holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content);//выводим родителей и детей
        holder.arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);//стрела
        holder.arrowstatick = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows);//стрела
        //((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).setOnClickListener(mArrowClickListener);//обрабокта нажатия на узел дерева
        //((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.content)).setOnClickListener(mArrowClickListener);//обрабокта нажатия на узел дерева
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (TreeListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    TreeViewNode node = displayNodes.get(position);
    holder.content.setText(node.getNodeName());
    ArrayList<Integer> lvl = new ArrayList<>();
    lvl.clear();
    lvl.add(node.getNodeLevel());

    for (Integer integer : lvl) {
        if (integer == 0){//если список развернут
            holder.arrow.setImageResource(0);
            holder.arrowstatick.setImageResource(0);
        }
        if (integer >= 1){//если список развернут
            holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_t);
            //holder.arrowstatick.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_i);
        }
        if (lvl.size() == integer) {
            holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_t);
        }
        for (TreeViewData data : dataList) {
            for (TreeViewData viewData : dataList) {
                if (data.getParentID() == viewData.getID() && data.getParentID() != -1) {
                //не работает
                //holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_l);
                }
            }
        }
        setNewWidth((integer * 60) + 1);
    }
    Log.d("newWidth", "- " + newWidth);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spacer)).getLayoutParams().width = getNewWidth();
    //((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).getLayoutParams().width = getNewWidth();//настраиваем выравнивание
    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
    if (getNewWidth() < 73) {
        Log.d("getNewWidth", "- " + getNewWidth());
        //((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).setImageDrawable(null);
    } else {
        //((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_i));
        //((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows2)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_i));
    }
    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows)).requestLayout();
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spacer)).requestLayout();

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Вот как наполняю:

```
data.add(new TreeViewData(0, "Захаров ", 1, -1));
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//корни
data.add(new TreeViewData(1, "Иванов 1", 2,  1));
data.add(new TreeViewData(1, "Иванов 2", 3,  1));
data.add(new TreeViewData(1, "Иванов 3", 4,  1));
data.add(new TreeViewData(1, "Иванов 4", 5,  1));

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 1", 9,  2));
data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 2", 10,  2));
data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 3", 11,  3));
data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 4", 12,  3));
data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 5", 13,  4));
data.add(new TreeViewData(2, "Адвокатовская 6", 14,  4));
data.add(new TreeViewData(3, "Адвокатовская 6.1", 15,  14));
data.add(new TreeViewData(3, "Адвокатовская 6.2", 16,  14));
```

**Повторю вопрос:**

Как соединить детей и родителей линиями у `ListView`? А точнее Захарова с Ивановым, т.е провести еще одну линию.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно реализовать цикл по всем предкам текущего элемента. Для каждого предка проверить есть ли у него брат (sibling) ниже. Если у предка брат есть, то добавлять у текущего элемента картинку с вертикальной линией, если нету, добавлять пустое место (картинку или пустой view, как удобно) в качестве отступа. Дополнительные отступы, которые у вас, как я понимаю, через `setNewWidth` реализованы, не нужны.

ЗЫ Аналогично надо проверять для элемента - последний ли он в списке братьев, и если последний, выводить картинку-уголок, а не `|-`.

**UPD**

Разметка layout/tree_view_cell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/arrows">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Отрисовка:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TreeListViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tree_view_cell, parent, false);
        holder = new TreeListViewHolder();
        holder.content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content);//выводим родителей и детей
        holder.arrows = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrows);//стрелки линии и т.д.
        holder.arrow = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);// уголок или стрелка
        convertView.setTag(holder);
   } else {
        holder = (TreeListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
   TreeViewNode node = displayNodes.get(position);
   holder.content.setText(node.getNodeName());
   TreeViewNode parent = node.getParent();
   holder.arrows.removeAllViews();
   while(parent!=null){ // для всех родителей
       ImageView spacer = new ImageView(holder.arrows.getContext());
       if(parent.hasNext()){ // у родителя есть братья ниже
           spacer.setImageResource(R.drawable.vert_line); //линия
       } else {
         spacer.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_box_same_size_as_vert_line); //пусто
       }
       holder.arrows.addView(spacer, 0); //идем в обратном порядке, поэтому всегда в начало вставляем
       parent = parent.getParent();
   }
   if(node.isLeaf()){ // лист
       if(node.hasNext()){ // есть братья ниже
           holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_t);// |-
       } else {
           holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_l);// |_
       }
   } else { 
       // аналогично для узлов, у которых есть дети. 
       // всеразличные ветвления на развернутость, наличие братьев ниже в зависимости нужны или нет соответствующие картинки для них
   }
   return convertView;
}
```

Тут потребуется реализация методов

- hasNext - есть ли братья ниже.

  ```
  public boolean hasNext(){
      // соответствующие проверки на null надо добавить
      return parent.children.size()>node.index+1;
  }
  ```
- isLeaf - есть ли дочерние элементы

  ```
  public boolean isLeaf(){
      return children.size()>0;
  }
  ```
- видимо еще expanded и т.д.

Comment: так я так пробовал,но все равно не получается вертикальную прямую провести

Comment: @upward дополнил ответ примером.

Comment: так я так и делал,только следуя вашей логике вы опять придете в к моему варианту,вот тестовый проект
https://yadi.sk/d/CAcqVZgp3E3uWZ

Comment: `etNewWidth`   задает уровень вложенности,если его убрать то дерево не получиться

Comment: К вашему варианту прийти сложно, т.к. у вас структура узла не содержит данных о родителях, а именно эта информация нужна чтоб решить задачу в вопросе. Кроме того, снипет, который я дал в ответе, недостаточно просто вставить в ваш код, чтоб все магически само заработало. Оно даже не компилируется. Это просто демонстрация алгоритма, считайте псевдокод. *Уровень вложенности* для решения вопроса вообще не нужен.

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov
вы меня не поняли,если я убираю `setNewWidth` т.е это мое древовидное отображение,то все гуд,линии все как надо отображаются,я это знаю и без алгоритмов